# JPackage getting ERROR: Unknown exception caught trying to find MSI installer

Tags: java, javafx, jpackage

I'm getting the following error in JPackage using JDK-19 and JavaFX-19. Same configuration used to work using JDK-18 and JavaFX-16. It builds the install image, but is missing the msi installer.

```
Required environment variables: 
 PATH_TO_FX      = C:\Java\javafx-19\sdk\lib
 PATH_TO_FX_MODS = C:\Java\javafx-19\jmods
 JPackage Version 19
```

```
[2022/11/12 10:46:54.801, jpackage.dll (PID: 5696, TID: 11192), jpackage.cpp:155 (Java_jdk_jpackage_internal_WinExeBundler_embedMSI)]
        ERROR: Unknown exception caught
[10:45:03.636] Running candle.exe
[10:45:03.647] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\candle.exe
[10:45:03.784] Running light.exe
[10:45:03.788] Running C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\light.exe
[10:45:03.989] Detected [candle.exe] version [3.11.2.4516].
[10:45:03.989] Detected [light.exe] version [3.11.2.4516].
[10:45:03.990] WiX 3.11.2.4516 detected. Enabling advanced cleanup action.
```

Any guidance or where I might get help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I needed to replace my boot drive, which involved reinstalling Windows and WIX Toolkit and Java plus all the other stuff. The error no longer occurs. I have no idea what fixed it, the new SSD is built the same as the old with the same versions of all software. There is not a software migration history on the new SSD as there was on the old HD. I'm using the same procedures as before.
I hate when we fix things and not know why, but such is life.